# Link a non entity to an entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm about to create a Symfony application with users existing elsewhere.

I have implemented a `UserProvider` and a `User` class not managed by doctrine.

Now I need to link users to entities (managed by Doctrine)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AuthCode
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\User")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

Of course Doctrine yells that `My\User` *is unknown or not an entity*

How should I link my non entity object ?

Comment: I don't think you can directly use doctrine to link the entites, but maybe a simple [entity listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) could do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Since Doctrine\ORM 2.5 you can use [embeddables](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/embeddables.html).

Also, you don't have to use `@ORM\ManyToOne` annotation at all.

It depends on how you want to use `$user` property further in your code.

Comment: This is interesting but does not seem to correspond to what I'm looking for. Embeddables data is actually persisted into the db.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your intention. How do you use `$user` and how does entity get it?

Comment: A `User` gets instantiated mainly from the `UserProvider`. For example a login page will check against the user source (a file, web service or whatever) and populate a `User` object which will be eventually attached to one of my entities.

Comment: And how does `User` get to `AuthCode`?

Answer (score 0):

Following [Yoshi's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425851#comment50834211_31425851) I ended up:

- Removing the schema annotations for `user`
- Overriding the user setter on `AuthCode` to actually store the username
- Using an entity listener with `postLoad()` to load the user object with `AuthCode`